# Set mipmap image as linearLayout background programmatically

Tags: android, background-image

I have a `.png` image in `mipmap` directory. know I want to set this image as the `linearLayout` background programmatically. and after some processes remove it.

```
target SDK : 23
min SDK    : 14
```

which function shall I use?

this can change background color:

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_mtn));
```

but where is background image?

Comment: l1.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.your_image));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.my_image);
```

or

```
ll.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.mipmap.my_image, null))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Both are Working**

```
iv_pic_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.generic_product_4);

or

iv_pic_image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.generic_product_4));
```